# Heroku Hdrive & Mulesoft Integration

Tags: heroku, mulesoft

I want store backup file via Mulesoft on Heroku Hdrive bucket.
I've configured a private S3 bucket but I'm not able to connect Mulesoft (throught S3 Connector) neither via S3 Browser client. In attach the access error from Mulesoft.
What can I do ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please paste the complete error in the question.

Comment: This is the error from Mulesoft:

Test connection failed: Access Denied (Service: Amazon S3:Status Code 404; Error Code AccesDenied; Request ID: .....


I've also tried to use the S3 Browse Client, and the error probably is more expicit: You are not allowed to get buckets list.

I'm sure that the credential are correct, an so I've open a Ticket to the Heroku Support to check if there is problems in the Heroku Hdrive addons configuration/environment.

Comment: Hi, it looks to be an authentication issue with Heroku rather than a problem with Mule. By the way, MuleSoft is a company name. The error is coming from some MuleSoft product, like Mule Runtime or Anypoint Studio.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Heroku Support team is working to fix the problem.